# Iam passing data in link tag through aboutProps but it returns this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'aboutProps' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, routerlink

I am sending aboutProps from here the following code (tagDisplay Co

```html
const queryParams = encodeURIComponent(tag.id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{tag.name}</h1>
      <Link to={{
        pathname: "NewChapter/" + tag.id,
        aboutProps: { queryParams }
      }} basic className="d-block">
        <Card type="floating p-1 px-3 mb-1" >
          <p>
            <b>Add New Chapter</b>
          </p>
        </Card>
      </Link>
```

I am receiving the aboutProps here

```html
const NewChapter = (props) => {
    console.log("about props" + props.location.aboutProps);


    const linkChapter = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: `<Link>` creates an `<a>` tag and not passing `aboutProps` down as you expect.

Comment: so then how should i pass data in it.